# How to make a lookup table with uint8_t associated to a string?

Tags: c, lookup-tables

I would like to make a lookup table with `uint8_t` associated to a `string`.

How do you think I can do this?

Here is my code:

```c
static const uint16_t ReadAccess[][2] =
{
        /* Value in b3b2 in byte 1, read access description */
        {0x0,           "ALWAYS"},
        {0x1,              "RFU"},
        {0x2,      "PROPRIETARY"},
        {0x3,              "RFU"}
};
```

Comment: C doesn't have standard `string` type. Do you mean one from `cs50.h`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *structures* to group members with multiple types to create one new type.

```
struct table_element {
        uint8_t intValue;
        const char* strValue;
};

static const struct table_element ReadAccess[] = {
        {0x0,           "ALWAYS"},
        {0x1,              "RFU"},
        {0x2,      "PROPRIETARY"},
        {0x3,              "RFU"}
};
```